# How to dynamically alter running test in Django

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing, django-tests

I have my test class as follows:

```
class MyTestCase(django.test.TestCase):
    def setUp(sefl):
        # set up stuff common to ALL the tests

    @my_test_decorator('arg1')
    @my_test_decorator('arg2')
    def test_something_1(self):
        # run test

    def test_something_2(self):
        # run test

    @my_test_decorator('arg1')
    @my_test_decorator('arg2')
    def test_something_3(self):
        # run test

    ...

    def test_something_N(self):
        # run test
```

Now, `@my_test_decorator` is a decorator I made that performs internal changes to setup some changes to the test environment at runtime and undo such changes after the test finished, but I need to do this to a specific set of test cases only, not to ALL of them and I would like to keep the setup general to all the tests and, for the specific tests, maybe do something like this:

```
def setUp(self):
    # set up stuff common to ALL the tests
    tests_to_decorate = ['test_something_1', 'test_something_3']
    decorator_args = ['arg1', 'arg2']

    if self._testMethodNamein in tests_to_decorate:
        method = getattr(self, self._testMethodNamein)
        for arg in decorator_args:
            method = my_test_decorator(arg)(method)
        setattr(self, self._testMethodNamein, method)
```

I mean, without repeating the decorators all over the file, but it seems that the test runner retrieves the set of tests to run even before instantiating the test class and thus is of no use doing this in the `__init__` or `setUp` methods.

It would be nice to have a way to accomplish this without:

1. having to write my own test runner
2. needing to split the tests in two or more `TestCase` subclasses
3. repeating `setUp` in different classes
4. creating a class that hosts the `setUp` method and have the `TestCase` subclasses inherit from such class

Is this even possible?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: Have a look at [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixtures) before writing your own test runner.